# How to only match once?

Tags: regex

My regex pattern looks something like

> •$389 PER MONTH FOR 36 months $4,314 DUE AT SIGNING SUGGESTED DEALER
>   CONTRIBUTION OF $1,385 Offer not valid in Puerto Rico. Lease financing
>   available on new 2017 BMW 330i xDrive Sports Wagon models from
>   participating BMW Centers through BMW Financial Services through
>   January 02, 2018, to eligible, qualified customers with excellent
>   credit history who meet BMW Financial Services' credit requirements.
>   Monthly lease payments of $389 per month for 36 months is based on an
>   adjusted capitalized cost of $38,210 (MSRP of $45,595, including
>   destination and handling fee of $995, less $3,000 customer down, $0
>   security deposit and suggested dealer contribution of $1,385 and
>   $3,000 Holiday Lease Credit). Actual MSRP may vary. Dealer
>   contribution may vary and could affect your actual monthly lease
>   payment. Cash due at signing includes $3,000 down payment, $389 first
>   month's payment, $925 acquisition fee and $0 security deposit. Lessee
>   responsible for insurance during the lease term, excess wear and tear
>   as defined in the lease contract, $0.25/mile over 30,000 miles and a
>   disposition fee of $350 at lease end. Not all customers will qualify
>   for security deposit waiver. Tax, title, license and registration fees
>   are additional fees due at signing. Advertised payment does not
>   include applicable taxes. Purchase option at lease end, excluding tax,
>   title and government fees, is $27,813. Offer valid through January 02,
>   2018 and may be combined with other offers unless otherwise stated.
>   Models pictured may be shown with metallic paint and/or additional
>   accessories. Visit your authorized BMW Center for important details.
>   ©2017 BMW of North America, LLC. The BMW name, model names and logo
>   are registered trademarks.

I want to match the number before months, which in this case is

> 36

However its coming out twice. is there a way to make it only match once?

I'm using `\d+\s*(?=( months+?))`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you have it twice in your text file.  If you want to match the first, you have to use the specifics of your tool.  With `grep` use `-m1` to exit after first match.

Comment: `36 months` appears *twice* in this text...

Comment: You need to tag with the programming language. Is it a multiline text?

Comment: Hello Karakfa, Thank you for answering my question. I've never use -m1 before. where in the code would i have to put it?

Comment: Hello Alfasin, Thank you for answering my question. yes i know it appears twice in my test. Is there a way to only capture it once?

Comment: Hello Yacc, Thank you for answering my question. How do I tag with the programming language? umm no I don't think its multi-line text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could find the first 36 before months from the start of the string and then capture it in a group:

[`^.*?(\d+)(?=\smonths)`](https://regex101.com/r/jrNWZm/1)

- Match the start of the string `^`
- Match any character 0 or more times non greedy `.*?`
- Capture 1 or more digits in a group `(\d+)`
- Positive lookahead if what follows is a whitespace and months `(?=\smonths)`

Comment: Hello thank you for answering my question. I tried your code but i it captures "$389 PER MONTH FOR 36 months" I want to only capture "36". I'm I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Omidff What you are capturing now is the whole match. The value you are looking for is in the first [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). Can you tell which programming language you are using or how you want to use this?